# Why does std::putchar(NULL) output a blank space?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, console

While working on a function that prints the raw contents of a binary file as characters, I noticed that some of the ASCII control characters don't always print single characters, or have other effects. This made wonder why `std::putchar('\0')` actually outputs a character, instead of nothing.

```
std::putchar('H');
std::putchar(NULL); // std::putchar('\0');
std::putchar('i');
```

outputs `H i`

```
std::putchar('H');
std::putchar(0x07); // std::putchar('\a');
std::putchar('i');
```

outputs `Hi`.
Does anyone know why `NULL` is printed as a space instead of nothing?

Comment: That's just how whichever terminal you are using chooses to display the character, I don't think many if any terminals are suitable for displaying binary data